# Simulate the Karhunen-Loeve expansion of Brownian motion in R

Tags: r

I want to simulate the Brownian motion using K-L expansion in R, here's the formula
in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karhunen%E2%80%93Lo%C3%A8ve_theorem#The_Wiener_process):

> There is a sequence {Z} of independent Gaussian random variables with mean zero and variance 1 such that
> [image: K-L expansion of Brownian motion]

However, when I simulated the Brownian motion, the simulated quadratic variation of Brownian motion [W]_t was not equal to t. This is contrary to the property of the Brownian motion. So I wonder which step went wrong?
Here's my R code:

```
set.seed(123)
###Simulate T independent days, each day has 23400 seconds (in a trading day).
N <- 23400; T <-10; K <- 1000;
t <- seq(1/N,1,length.out = N)
W <- matrix(0,nrow=T,ncol=N)
Z <- matrix(rnorm(T*K),T,K)
phi <- function(t,k) sqrt(2)*sin((k-1/2)*pi*t)/((k-1/2)*pi)
phi1 <- sapply(t,phi,k=1:K)#K*N
W <-Z%*%phi1
###Calculate the quadratic variation in T days independently
sapply(1:T, function(i,W)sum(diff(W[i,])^2),W=W)
###output:
> [1] 0.04308167 0.04053284 0.04245134 0.04322369 0.04356512 0.04667812 0.04203774 0.04052012 0.04223466 0.04157220
```

The desired output should approximately equal to 1 for each element since [W,W]_1=1. So what's wrong in my codes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like you are only a factor of `N/K` out.

Comment: @pseudospin I guess this is because K is not big enough, when I fix N and take K=10000,50000, $[W,W]_1$ becomes closer to 1.